# E2E tests with Espresso: Keep application open after finishing a @Test/properly structuring larger test cases

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

**What I do**

I want to build a "happy path"-style end-to-end test for my Android application. It involves a number of steps that need to be performed:

1. Swipe through multiple slides of an on-boarding screen
2. Click a "Finish onboarding" button
3. Fill in a registration form
4. Click a registration button and wait for registration to be finished
5. Open the main screen and perform the actual functional tests

While I am able to implement all of that, I do stumble upon one issue. After each `@Test`-annotated function, the application is closed and restarted. Now with an e2e-testing scenario like mine, where each step depends on the previous one, that doesn't work too well.

**What I have**

To avoid that issue, right now, I have all my individual test steps broken down into individual functions and call them all from one central `@Test` function (they're named more appropriately in my actual code):

```
@Test
public void followHappyPath() {
    performStep1();
    performStep2();
    performStep3();
}

private void performStep1() {
   // ...
}

// ...
```

This runs the tests just fine, but I get no detailed reporting per test case (e.g. "Success: it should show the registration form").

**What I want**

What I would prefer instead, would be a setup like this:

```
@Test
public void itShouldPerformStep1() {
}

@Test
public void itShouldPerformStep2() {
}
// ...
```

That would enable me to get a more detailed reporting per test case.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You can annotate class with `@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)` to run test in alphabetical order, but your tests should never depend on one another! If your app experience relies on SharedPreferences, you can preload them in the setup before you run the tests.

Comment: I'd agree for unit tests or any other form of isolated test of single components. But the point of an end to end test is to exactly have components depend on one another.